# Auto tab back in VIM

Tags: vim

How can i do that gvim will auto tab back when I write the word 'end'
(like it does when Im write '}')

I add this rows to gvimrc

```
set smartindent
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a plugin like `vim-endwise` to achieve this. This plugin will de-indent the current line when you type `end` accordingly. Not only that, if for example you are using Ruby, then the plugin will insert `end` appropriately, whenever you are starting a method or a condition and so on, like `def`, `if`, etc.

More Information: https://github.com/tpope/vim-endwise

Comment: I second `vim-endwise`. Great, as expected by the Pope!

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing in one of the languages that vim recognizes, then chances are good that someone has already written an indentation plugin.  Try

```
:filetype indent on
:e foo.???
:help :filetype-indent-on
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so first of all: don't use smartindent. Use filetype-specific indent rules. Vim has built-in support for many file types, or you can define your own using 'indentexpr', see `:help 30.3` and `:help indent-expression`.

When using the 'indentexpr' option, another option called 'indentkeys' defines when Vim will automatically adjust the indent.